# how to make innerhtml values as user inputs

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I am trying to get the innerElement to a value that is entered by the user but it give me errors. Codes are as above please help

*****Codes*****

```
var abc= document.getElementById("searchbar").innerHTML = "Singapore Polytechnic"; --instead of Singapore Polytechnic I want it to be some values that was entered by the users.--

      document.getElementById("searchbar").contentEditable = "true";

      var test = abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
function changeVal(ele){
    document.getElementById("searchbar").innerHTML = ele.value;
    }
```

```html
<p id="searchbar">Test</p>
<input value="Hit enter to change value" id="val" onchange="changeVal(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no plan what the point of your question is but maybe you look for this...

```
var foo = document.getElementById('id_of_input_field').value; // get
document.getElementById('id_of_input_field').value = 'value to set'; // set
```

Comment: the thing is that it does not have the property value but it has the property of innerhtml only

Comment: can you send your #searchbar field ? because typicaly every html input (input, textarea...) got a value field. You can also try using  `.nodeValue`

Comment: the thing is that I could hard code the values into the searchbox but if I do not hard code the values, it cannot work. I want the searchbox to work without hard code values into it

Comment: Tried using the .nodeValue method it works only for the hard code values but it do not work for the user input values

Comment: can you send the `html` snipped of the input. seems pretty weired to me that this doesn't work

Comment: <ion-searchbar id="searchbar" name="searchbar" onchange="myInput" autocomplete="on"></ion-searchbar>

Comment: are you using angular ?

Comment: then you can just use  `[(ngModel)]="foo"` and there you have your input content

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

**Code**

```
<input value="variable" id="val" onchange="changeVal(this)">
```

**TS**

```
onchange(this){
    let var  = event.target.getElementsByTagName('input').value;
}
```